# Filter or Reduce posts within .Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

So I want to have the option filter a featured post out of posts in a react component. Specifically for Gatsby.js. All while doing so in one component instead of two to reduce the amount of code I write. This way the component can show a list of blog posts or just the featured posts based on whether featured is on or off.

So I have the following code with an idea of what I am trying to accomplish

```
const BlogRoll = ({ data, featured }) => {
  const { edges: posts } = data
  return (
    <div>
      {posts && 
        posts.map(({ node: post }) => (
          <div>
            if featured than posts.filter(post.featuredpost) or post.title (listing all of the posts instead)
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in the posts && posts.map section? I know I can do a regular if and else statement but I know I don't have to write the same code snippet twice.

Answer (score 2):

you can use normal javascript array opperations inside jsx, in your case you can filter the array by the `featured` flag, then display the result:

```js
const posts = [
  {
    featuredpost: true,
    title: "Featured Post"
  },
  {
    title: "Normal Post"
  },
  {
    featuredpost: true,
    title: "Featured Post 2"
  },
  {
    title: "Normal Post 2"
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [appPosts, setAppPosts] = React.useState(posts);

  const toggle = event => {
    setAppPosts(
      event.target.checked ? posts.filter(post => post.featuredpost) : posts
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={toggle} />
        Just Featured.
      </label>
      {appPosts.map(post => (
        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />,rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Apologies, I updated my question to say that I want the option to filter featured posts. That way the component will have the ability to show featured posts or all posts.

Comment: No worries, I updated the above snippet, I also added some state to it.

Comment: you should try to have as little logic as possible inside the template, try to keep your logic in component methods.